# Checking whether there is only one occurrence of maximum in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4 x 4 numpy array. I would like determine whether the maximum of each row is unique, i.e. there is only one occurrence of the maximum value. I'm new to Python and numpy and wondered if there is a pythonic way (method) of doing this rather than running a for loop.

Comment: So you want to check if in a row of 4 values the maximum value is strictly greater than the 3 other values? Or is there an interdependence between the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example, try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 4))
res = np.sum(x == x.max(axis=1, keepdims=True), axis=1) > 1
```

This gives you a boolean array. Its nth index is `True` if the maxima of the nth row of the input array occurs multiple times in the same row.

`x.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)` computes the maxima along the rows of the array and ensures that the result has the same number of dimensions as the input. Then it checks if there are further occurrences of the maxima in the corresponding rows. The result is boolean array of the same shape as the input array. In Python, booleans are effectively integer values, so you can sum them up. If sum is greater than 1, the maximum is not strict.